# `ActiveRecord::Enum` values and some methods identified by IRB tab completion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's some Rails console output for the `ActiveRecord::Enum` doc example:

```
irb(main):012:0> Conversation.statuses
=> {"active"=>0, "archived"=>1}
irb(main):013:0> Conversation.statuses.archived
Conversation.statuses.archived
Conversation.statuses.archived!
Conversation.statuses.archived?
irb(main):013:0> Conversation.statuses.archived
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):13
NoMethodError (undefined method `archived` for {"active"=>0, "archived"=>1}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess)
irb(main):016:0> Conversation.statuses.methods.grep(/arch/)
=> []
```

Line 2 shows tab completion output, but calling any of those returns a `NoMethodError` (during app runtime too).

What's happening there? These "exist" but aren't usable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below instance method will update the enum value as specified. In the below example it will update the first conversation status to 'archived'

```
Conversation.first.archived!
```

The below code will return if the status of the conversation is `archived`

```
Conversation.first.archived? # Will return true/false based on the status of the conversation
```

With the below code you can get the value of the enum

```
Conversaion.statuses[:archived] # 1
Conversaion.statuses[:active] # 0
```